# InDesign: how to type a hedera/fleuron symbol?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

How do you type a hedera/[fleuron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography)) symbol in InDesign using less effort?

Comment: I've been trying to do this via Unicode but Indesign doesn't accept the codes like other apps on Windows, it seems... The characters do not match

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using less effort"? Lucian did explain in his answer how to use the glyph panel to insert this symbol. But do you want to go further and, for instance: use a keyboard shortcut to insert this symbol? Use autocorrection to transform a text pattern into this symbol while typing? or do you have any other effortless workflow in mind?

Comment: If you're on a Windows system, you could also use AutoHotkey to set up text expansion for these characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that there are some Unicode characters that will work on Windows with Microsoft programs but not in InDesign. I worked for a company for a while that had a glyph as part of their name, and I used a couple of tricks.  Make sure you always use a font that contains that glyph, then assign a keyboard shortcut to insert the glyph.  I also set up a custom search and replace to allow me to type the name without the glyph and then run a search/replace that added the glyph in.

In your case, assuming you are using this character to designate the end of a paragraph, or sentence, etc., I would create a paragraph style using GREP styles, that will automatically insert the symbol before a paragraph return (for example) in paragraphs using that style.

Answer (score 3):

You use a font which includes one. There is a list of such fonts at the bottom of the page in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography)#External_links) you provided. With a font like this installed, insert the symbol in InDesign using the '[Glyphs](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/glyphs-special-characters.html)' panel.